Pointwise and total convergence of a real function series.
Exercise
Consider the function series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^x x^n.
$$

Find the biggest $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ such that the series converges pointwise for every $x\in X$.
Is the series totally convergent in $X$?
If the answer to 2. is no, find some intervals where the series converges totally.

Solution

The series is absolutely convergent for every $x\in]-1,1[$, and for $x=-1$ the series is convergent as a consequence of the Leibniz test; for $x\in\mathbb{R}\diagdown[-1,1[$, the sequence that defines the series does not converge to $0$, hence the series cannot be convergent; hence, $X=[-1,1[$.

The series is not totally convergent in $X$, since we have


$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sup_{x\in X}|n^x x^n|=\sum_{n=1}^\infty1=\infty.
$$

Such an interval $I$ must be such that $I\subseteq X$, since total convergence on $I$ implies pointwise convergence on $I$. The biggest such $I$s are those of the form

$$
[-a,a],\qquad 0<a<1,
$$
since we have
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sup_{x\in I}|n^x x^n|=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^a a^n<\infty.
$$
These $I$s are the biggest possible in the sense that, given an interval $J$ such that $J\subseteq X$ and the series converges totally on $J$, we have that $J\subseteq [-a,a]$, for $a$ big enough, $0<a<1$.
I wanted to know if the solution provided to this exercise is correct, and in case if there are better ways to justify the answers.

For part 1, it's not clear to me why $X$ must be an interval.
